# Xamarin Form Animation

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I have a simple code that uses ScaleTo method to build a simple animation and the code was working fine up to last Friday and all of the sudden it's not working any more.
Here is my XAML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         mc:Ignorable="d"
         x:Class="TestAnim.MainPage">
  <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
    <Image Source="discount.png" x:Name="img" Scale="0.1"/>
    <Button Text="Do" Clicked="doIt"/>
  </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

And here is my C# code:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using Xamarin.Forms;
namespace TestAnim
{
  [DesignTimeVisible(false)]
  public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
  {
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    async void doIt (object sender , EventArgs ev)
    {
        await img.ScaleTo(1, 2000, Easing.BounceOut);
        await img.ScaleTo(0.1, 3000, Easing.BounceIn);
    }
  }
}
```

When I run the code, I see no effects at all, if I comment the 2nd ScaleTo call I see my image scales to 1 but this happens immediately instead of within 2 seconds! As result when I have the 2nd scale really the end result is no see no animation at all. 
This was working fine before as I mentioned but for some reason the duration seems to be ignored and the scaling seems to happen instantly which is the issue here.
Any one else see the same problem?

Comment: What xamarin.forms version are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Xamarin.Forms version 4.2+ there is currently a bug about Animations, you can track it [here](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/7291).

I've reproduced your code in Xamarin.Forms 4.1.0.581479 and it is working just fine.

Comment: I'm using 4.2 and saw the ticket, I'll be watching the fix, thx

Comment: Downgraded to 4.1.0.709244 and it works again for now while the fix is release.